# How do I make it so that when I double click on a div, it doesn't select the word?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to double click on a div, but right now it "selects"/highlights a word. How do I make it so that this doesn't happen?

I tried:

```
$(this).hide().show()

and 

$(this).blur()
```

But it still highlights the word.

Comment: Because I currently have a click event attached to this div. But I don't want to highlight the word when people accidently double click.

Comment: Then you probably want to prevent the element from being selected at all.

Comment: I would recommend not doing this - it's a pain very very often from a UX perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent an element from being selected in most browsers like this:

```
elem.onselectstart = function() { return false; }; 
elem.unselectable = "on"; 
$(elem).css({ "-moz-user-select": 'none', "-webkit-user-select": 'none' });
```

You could try doing that in the `click` event and undoing it one or two seconds later using `setTimeout`.

Comment: shouldn't selectstart do an `e.preventDefault` here?

Comment: kibibu: No. `return false` is all you need for event handlers assigned via the "DOM0" method, i.e. assigning the event handler function to the appropriate property. This works in all browsers. The `preventDefault()` of the event only comes into play for event handlers assigned via `addEventListener()`.

Comment: I did this and it works in Firefox. But how do I make it work for IE?

Comment: alex: `elem.unselectable = "on";` should be doing that for you. However, if `elem` has children, you need to set `unselectable` to "on" for them too, and likewise for their children. Writing a function to do this recursively helps.